# Angular Custom Filters For Some Nested JSON Objects

Tags: angular, angular-filters

I want to use an Angular filter for Users based on their MAC Address for devices they are currently using. I have some JSON data and my trial custom filter I need help with.

My Trial Custom filter:

```js
  getCurrentUser(): User {
    return USERS.filter((user) => user.devices, mac_id == 44:44:44:44:44)[0];
  }
```

```js
export const USERS: User[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    email: 'yacie.qbi.com',
    pword: '123',
    fname: 'Tatenda Y',
    lname: 'Gatsi',
    date: '2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z',
    sa: 1,
    devices: [
      {
        mac_id: '33:33:33:33:33',
        imei: 91011,
        fone_no: 8888,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    email: 'chiko.qbi.com',
    pword: '123',
    fname: 'Tatenda Y',
    lname: 'Gatsi',
    date: '2015-09-16T02:00:28.015982Z',
    sa: 1,
    devices: [
      {
        mac_id: '44:44:44:44:44',
        imei: 91011,
        fone_no: 8888,
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I expect to get results like:
User ID and Mac_id in HTML like

```html
  <mat-card *ngIf="user" fxFlex>
    <mat-card-content>
      <div>User ID: {{user.id}}</div>
      <div>Current MAC Address: {{user.devices.mac_id}}</div>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
```

Comment: `devices` is an array. You have to access its elements by their index, like `devices[0].mac_id`. Are you trying to display all users? Then use `*ngFor` and only display selected properties of each user. You don't need any filters to do that.

Comment: I just want to display the User with the mac_id of "44:44:44:44:44". -Thanx for a prompt one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on additional info from comments, you want to display one user with `mac_id` of `'44:44:44:44:44'`.

Your filter function isn't right. `devices` is an array and you aren't searching that array. You can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if at least one device has given `mac_id`.

```
getCurrentUser(): User { 
  // Only returning first user from filtered users.
  return USERS.filter(user => 
    user.devices.some(item => item.mac_id === '44:44:44:44:44'))[0];
}
```

Then modify your HTML to display this user. `devices[0]` gives first device in `devices` array.

```
<mat-card *ngIf="user" fxFlex>
  <mat-card-content>
    <div>User ID: {{user.id}}</div>
    <div>Current MAC Address: {{user.devices[0].mac_id}}</div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```